# If a function has an antiderivative, is it always integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

If a function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ has an antiderivative on $[a,b]$, is it always Riemann integrable?  I can't think of a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not necessary; a counterexample is the derivative of [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).